# Any way to schedule multiple reports at a time in JasperReports Server?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler, jasperserver

Is there any way to schedule more than one report at a time in *JasperReports Server*? I love the software and the scheduler but individually scheduling reports is a drag.

If there is not, can you recommend the quickest path to achieving this via customization? What kind of objects would need to be written?